# codeigniter phpbb3 library style integration

Tags: php, codeigniter, integration, phpbb3

How to integrate the whole forum with the library in to my site page? I want my site page, to be around the  forum. For example i have hader, footer, menu and etc. for the site, and somewhere to be the forum in it?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the **phpbb3 theme/template** to look like your site. There is *no* integration unless you mean something like:

- User account / login integration
- Site user specific settings that need to carry over to phpbb3.

In which case you have some coding ahead of you mainly inside phpbb3.

However if I understand correctly you just want it 'sitting' in your webroot like so:

- `/` - website
- `/forum` - phpbb3 forum (with website look).

So to re-iterate just create a theme for phpbb3 to match your site

Comment: There was some whay doing that thing.I know about the template but it doesn't working for me.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work for you? please be specific and describe your problem correctly or nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: I don't want to design the template, i want to put the forum in the site, there are a lot of forums made like that, just i'm asking with that library how can it happen

Comment: You are still not clarifying what you want.  What is "forum in the site" mean? Same directory in the webroot? Or INCLUDE the WHOLE phpbb3 as a library (not going to happen!)